# Рисуется не верно ось метода наименьших квадратов на python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, методы

есть такой код

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# x_train = np.array([x for x in range(30)])
# y_train = np.array([1*x+random.randint(0,10) for x in x_train])
x_train = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y_train = np.array([1.1,3.8,6.5,10.2,13.1])
sum_X_Y = np.sum(x_train*y_train)
sum_X = sum(x_train)
sum_Y = sum(y_train)
sum_X_kvad = sum(x_train**2)
one_del = len(x_train)*sum_X_Y-sum_X*sum_Y
sum_x_kwad = sum_X**2
two_del = len(x_train)*sum_X_kvad-sum_x_kwad
a = one_del/two_del
one_del_two = sum_Y-a*sum_X
b = one_del_two/len(x_train)
print(a,b)
y_sel = np.array([a*x-b for x in x_train])
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
plt.plot(x_train, y_sel, color='red')
plt.xlim([0, 45])
plt.ylim([0, 75])
plt.ylabel("длина")
plt.xlabel("ширина")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

почему эта ось смещается как это исправить помогите понять, пожалуйста

[image: ось]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот заменить эту строчку

```
y_sel = np.array([a*x-b for x in x_train])
```

На эту

```
y_sel = np.array([a * x + b for x in x_train])
```

Comment: офигеть все сработал,спасибо большое